# why is my actual output and developer tool layout differing?

Tags: html, css, flexbox, google-chrome-devtools

[image: bottom section]

What comes on the screen outlined as a small red box above the white background/greenyellow bordered divs has got different dimension than what is shown on the developer tool layout.
In layout it is as per the
**HTML**

```
<div class="bottom">
        <div>   
          <div>
          Colton Smith 
          Verified Buyer
          "We needed the same printed design as the one we had ordered a week prior.
          Not only did they find the original order, but we also received it in time.
          Excellent!"
        </div>     
      </div>
        <div>      
          <div>
          Irene Roberts 
          Verified Buyer
          "Customer service is always excellent and very quick turn around. Completely
          delighted with the simplicity of the purchase and the speed of delivery."
        </div> 
       </div>
        <div>      
          <div class=>
            Anne Wallace 
            Verified Buyer
            "Put an order with this company and can only praise them for the very high
            standard. Will definitely use them again and recommend them to everyone!" 
          </div> 
        </div>
         
      </div>
```

**CSS code**

```
.bottom{
        width: 100%;
        background-image: url(./images/bg-pattern-bottom-desktop.svg);
        padding: 8%;
        display: flex;
      }
      

      .bottom>div:before{
        border: 1px solid red;
        content: "\00a0";
        width: 1500px!important;
        height:50px;

      }
      .bottom>div>div{
        border:2px solid greenyellow;
      }
```

> that is *1550x50* the actual space
> on screen
> *6.61 x 22.8*
> why is it becoming shortened on display?

Comment: Maybe a glitch in dev tools?

Comment: the dev tool is showing exactly as per css. What comes in the output is very strange. I mean how were those numbers arrived at? 6.61 x 22.8

Comment: Usually the units of the box that appears when we hover are in px. Maybe it shows a different unit. I would not worry about that a lot as long as your code is working